# Haskell CIS194 Spring 13 Homework 6 Exercise 5

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf

The question is about representing the ruler function

> 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, . . .
>   where the nth element in the stream (assuming the first element
>   corresponds to n = 1) is the largest power of 2 which evenly divides n

I have working solution using show to display the first 20 elements with interleaveStreams' function:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons a b) = a : streamToList b 

instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
  show = show . take 20 . streamToList

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat a = Cons a (streamRepeat a)

ruler :: Stream Integer
ruler = 
  let s n = interleaveStreams' (streamRepeat n) (s (n+1)) 
  in s 0

interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons x (Cons y (interleaveStreams xs ys))

interleaveStreams' :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams' (Cons x xs) y = Cons x $ interleaveStreams' y xs
```

However I don't understand why ruler using the interleave function instead does not terminate with Show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first congrats - you solved the *hard* part ;)

To your question: if you use the `interleaveStreams` than it will pattern match on the second `Cons` too - but if you look at your code you see that the second part is generated by:

```
let s n = interleaveStreams ... (s (n+1))
```

so if `interleaveStreams` now asks it to *produce* a `Cons` for this part too you end up in an infinite loop

The other function solves this issue by *only* forcing the first constructor, which you get at once from`streamRepeat`

#### interleaveStreams:

```
s 0
= interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (s 1))
{ need both cons }
= interleaveStreams (Cons 0 (streamRepeat 0)) (s 1)
= interleaveStreams (Cons ...) (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 1) (s 2))
{ the inner interleaveStream needs both Cons again for it's pattern }
= ...
```

you'll never get to a `Cons` and `streamToList` will never be able to produce a list-cons and then you have your problem

#### interleaveStreams':

```
s 0
= interleaveStreams' (streamRepeat 0) (s 1))
{ need only first Cons for the pattern-match }
= interleaveStreams' (Cons 0 (streamRepeat 0)) (s 1)
= Cons 0 $ interleaveStreams' (s 1) (streamRepeat 0)
= ...
```

as you can see you get the `Cons` which is the happy path for laziness in `show`/`streamToList`

---

#### a bit shorter

by the way: you can write this without the `s` inner-function by using `streamMap`:

```
ruler :: Stream Integer
ruler = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (streamMap (+1) ruler)
```